# Chrome crash: Attempt to invoke virtual method "long android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.getSourceNodeId()" on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, keepass

While working on the Search form (JavaScript, CSS, HTML) of my web page, the Chrome browser (Android 10) crashes every time when I click on the web search icon and the input field is focused.

The debug stack trace in the crash report says

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method "long android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.getSourceNodeId()" on a null object reference
at android.view.View.populateVirtualStructure(View.java:9942)
```

Image of Event log during crash
[image: Image of Event log during crash]

This crash obviously is a bug.
The question is: where should I create the bug ticket?

I found the description of the AccessibilityNodeInfo, it seems to be a basic Android feature: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo

I also found in this discussion https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369434/trying-to-comment-on-a-particular-question-on-the-full-site-crashes-android-chro that the Android Accessibility Service or the AutoFill Service might be involved in this.

Indeed, when I turn off the AutoFill feature of my KeePass password manager, Chrome no longer crashes.

So:

1. a form field on my web page is focused.
2. Then, chrome gives the focus event to the autofill Service
3. The AutoFill Service checks if there are some search suggestions or other insertable texts
4. The KeePass AutoFill feature is called.

As I am no Java/Android App developer, I need your help to find the correct recipient for this issue:

1. Could my HTML/CSS/JS code be responsible for this problem? (The search field only crashes on one special page and works fine on others)
2. Is this a chrome@android bug?
3. Is this a bug in the Accessibility Service of Android?
4. Or could it be a bug in the KeePass App for Android?

Which steps would you recommend to identify the clear source of the bug?

Thank you!

Comment: Getting the same crash using LastPass. Your post made it possible for me to narrow down. However, when I reinstalled LastPass, the crash STOPPED occurring. This is very weird. I'll keep you updated if we manage to reproduce it.

Comment: Same issue here with Enpass. Weird stuff.

Comment: Just submitted a bug report to Chrome/Chrmium: https://crbug.com/1280378

Comment: Also seeing this on Brave Browser (chromium based) while using Bitwarden. Tested on grouvee.com by clicking on the search button/input (may have to click it twice). Disabling Bitwarden as autofill service prevents the crash.

Comment: I've also seen this crash very often in Chrome with Bitwarden installed. Not sure exact steps to replicate, but it happens often when I click in the search field on Google. Haven't been able to fix it yet.

Comment: I've started seeing this crash since around early April. My app uses the `WebView` a lot but I don't see it mentioned on the stack trace anywhere.