# Application crash sometimes on a WebView screen

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, crash, autofill

Application crash sometimes on the activity with WebView with exception

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.getSourceNodeId()' on a null object reference
```

Seems like problem is similar to the next and seems like related to bug in WebView.
[Chrome crash: Attempt to invoke virtual method "long android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.getSourceNodeId()" on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69428809/chrome-crash-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-long-android-view-accessibility)

Any ideas why this can happens?

Attaching full logs with the problem

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.getSourceNodeId()' on a null object reference
       at android.view.View.populateVirtualStructure(View.java:9856)
       at android.view.View.onProvideVirtualStructureCompat(View.java:8970)
       at android.view.View.onProvideVirtualStructure(View.java:8952)
       at android.view.View.dispatchProvideStructure(View.java:10002)
       at android.view.View.dispatchProvideStructure(View.java:9949)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideStructure(ViewGroup.java:3565)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideStructure(ViewGroup.java:3638)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideStructure(ViewGroup.java:3638)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideStructure(ViewGroup.java:3638)
       at android.app.assist.AssistStructure$WindowNode.<init>(AssistStructure.java:530)
       at android.app.assist.AssistStructure.<init>(AssistStructure.java:2205)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRequestAssistContextExtras(ActivityThread.java:3837)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:250)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7848)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:609)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1070)

bc:
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:200)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

DefaultDispatcher-worker-1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:353)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.park(CoroutineScheduler.java:17)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.tryPark(CoroutineScheduler.java:17)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.java:17)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.java:17)

AudioPortEventHandler:
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:200)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

GmsDynamite:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:568)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.zza.run(zza.java:6)

Chrome_ProcessLauncherThread:
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:200)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

CleanupReference:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:190)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:211)
       at ck.run(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-561510130:3)

he.u www.google.com:
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java)
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:119)
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:176)
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:144)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:936)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:900)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readUntilDataAvailable(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:815)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:788)
       at okio.InputStreamSource.k0(InputStreamSource.java:45)
       at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.k0(AsyncTimeout.java:12)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.java:2)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.require(RealBufferedSource.java)
       at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Reader.nextFrame(Http2Reader.java:14)
       at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$ReaderRunnable.invoke(Http2Connection.java:1)
       at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$ReaderRunnable.invoke(Http2Connection.java:1)
       at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskQueue$execute$1.runOnce(TaskQueue.java:2)
       at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner.runTask(TaskRunner.java:3)
       at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner.access$runTask(TaskRunner.java:3)
       at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner$runnable$1.run(TaskRunner.java:7)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

FinalizerDaemon:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:190)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:211)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:273)
       at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

pool-9-thread-2:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

arch_disk_io_1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

queued-work-looper:
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:200)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

he.u TaskRunner:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner$RealBackend.coordinatorWait(TaskRunner.java:24)
       at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner.awaitTaskToRun(TaskRunner.java:13)
       at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner.access$getLogger$cp(TaskRunner.java:3)
       at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner$Companion.getLogger(TaskRunner.java:3)
       at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner$runnable$1.run(TaskRunner.java:3)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

Firebase Background Thread #3:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(CustomThreadFactory.java:12)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

he.u t1.gstatic.com:
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java)
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:119)
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:176)
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:144)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:936)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:900)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readUntilDataAvailable(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:815)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:788)
       at okio.InputStreamSource.k0(InputStreamSource.java:45)
       at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.k0(AsyncTimeout.java:12)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.java:2)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.require(RealBufferedSource.java)
       at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Reader.nextFrame(Http2Reader.java:14)
       at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$ReaderRunnable.invoke(Http2Connection.java:1)
       at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$ReaderRunnable.invoke(Http2Connection.java:1)
       at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskQueue$execute$1.runOnce(TaskQueue.java:2)
       at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner.runTask(TaskRunner.java:3)
       at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner.access$runTask(TaskRunner.java:3)
       at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner$runnable$1.run(TaskRunner.java:7)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

Crashlytics Exception Handler1:
       at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(VMStack.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1736)
       at java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1812)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.populateThreadsList(:16)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.populateExecutionData(:4)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.populateEventApplicationData(:45)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsReportDataCapture.captureEventData(:44)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.SessionReportingCoordinator.persistEvent(SessionReportingCoordinator.java:19)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.SessionReportingCoordinator.persistFatalEvent(SessionReportingCoordinator.java:32)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$2.call(:49)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$2.call()
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker$3.then(:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zze.run(zze.java:26)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(:2)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(:5)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

PlatformServiceBridgeHandlerThread:
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:200)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

arch_disk_io_2:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

GoogleApiHandler:
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:200)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

pool-9-thread-1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.startup1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(:2)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(:5)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

ConnectivityThread:
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:200)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

DefaultDispatcher-worker-4:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:353)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.park(CoroutineScheduler.java:17)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.tryPark(CoroutineScheduler.java:17)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.java:17)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.java:17)

Firebase Background Thread #1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(CustomThreadFactory.java:12)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

arch_disk_io_0:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

ReferenceQueueDaemon:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:568)
       at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:217)
       at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

arch_disk_io_3:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

FinalizerWatchdogDaemon:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:568)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepUntilNeeded(Daemons.java:341)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:321)
       at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:139)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

DefaultDispatcher-worker-2:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:353)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.park(CoroutineScheduler.java:17)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.tryPark(CoroutineScheduler.java:17)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.java:17)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.java:17)

awaitEvenIfOnMainThread task continuation executor1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(:2)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(:5)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

bm:
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:200)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

Firebase Background Thread #2:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(CustomThreadFactory.java:12)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

pool-7-thread-1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

DefaultDispatcher-worker-3:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:353)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.park(CoroutineScheduler.java:17)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.tryPark(CoroutineScheduler.java:17)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.java:17)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.java:17)

Firebase Background Thread #0:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.concurrent.CustomThreadFactory.lambda$newThread$0(CustomThreadFactory.java:12)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I tried to reproduce the issue but did not find any specific steps. Logs attached from the Crashlytics.

Comment: This bug has been fixed long ago. Could you please go into Play Store, update WebView, restart your device and try again? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview

Comment: Hey, I am experiencing the very same issue. Have been able to resolve this?

Comment: No, issue is not fixed yet